# Having trouble playing certain song from another view controller that is in a table view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a system where there is an album with a list of songs and when I press the song It brings be to a player view controller. Like Apple Music and Spotify. These songs are in a file on my computer. They already are showing up in a list in my AlbumSongViewController, but when I press that song and it segues to my PlayerViewController I doesn't play the song. Any help, I feel very stuck.

I will be showing the code where I think there is a issue. I will add more if needed.

AlbumSongViewController:

```
 var song: [Song] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    retrieveSongs()
}

//Delegate and source for tableview
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return song.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SongsTableViewCell
    cell.mainLabel.text = song[indexPath.row].getName()
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

PlayerViewController:

```
var player: Player!
var song: [Song] = []
let indexPath = IndexPath()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    player = Player()
    setSession()
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    becomeFirstResponder()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("handleInterruption")), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)



     func tableView(_ tableView: AlbumSongViewController, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    player.playStream(fileUrl: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles" + song[indexPath.row].getName())
    changePlayButton()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest breaking your functionality into pieces to find out the actual issue. Is it with the table view and selecting a song? Or is it with plain a correctly selected song? Maybe the segue? I would probably start by combining everything into one VC (or keep two VCs but see that you are passing things properly).

Comment: @dfd Thank you for the response. My goal is to have it like apple music so I would think I would have to do two VCs, but I think it has to do with playing a correctly selected song. The segue work but when I go to the playerVC nothing plays.

Comment: do your PlayerViewController have tableView ?

Comment: where you are performing segue ?

Comment: You probably do need two VCs, but I was trying to break down things to identify the actual issue. *"...nothing plays."* is a symptom but what's the cause? My initial guess is that the song (title? MP3?) isn't being pass into the player VC properly. But even that isn't the real issue. What is it you are passing through the segue?

Comment: @dfd thank you for the response, I posted the answer but it was because there were spaces like, trial song.mp3. It should have been trial_song.mp3.

Comment: All told, your edit of the question, along with the answer, is pretty much what this site is about! I upvoted your answer - I'm sure others will encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

The problem was that there were space in the cell. For example, `trial song.mp3`. This messed things up when it tried to get the song from the database.

**The Solution**

I forgot that it messes things up when there are spaces. When you put a song in your database remember that you should do for example, `trial_song.mp3`.